Some programs report "no route to host" connecting to servers when run without sudo
On my Windows 11 machine, at 10.204.221.106, I'm running a netcat listener:
ncat.exe -lv 31415

On macOS Sequoia 15.0.1, I can successfully connect to the Windows machine with nc like this:
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:MacOS andrewtapia$ nc 10.204.221.106 31415
hello
there
^C

But I get an error using telnet:
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:MacOS andrewtapia$ telnet 10.204.221.106 31415
Trying 10.204.221.106...
telnet: connect to address 10.204.221.106: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Telnet is version 303.141.1 of this brew formula.
Unless I run telnet with sudo:
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:MacOS andrewtapia$ sudo telnet 10.204.221.106 31415
Trying 10.204.221.106...
Connected to tatl.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
there
^]
telnet> Connection closed.

Evidently, this works even if I use sudo to become a non-root user, e.g., sudo -u nobody telnet 10.204.221.106 31415.
This problem also occurs when I attempt to connect to netcat listeners on any other computers on the network from the Mac, but it does not occur if I run a listener on the Mac itself and attempt to connect to localhost.
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:~ andrewtapia$ telnet localhost 31415
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
there
^]
telnet> Connection closed.

I don't have a .telnetrc file.
The problem persists even if I disable rDNS lookup with the -N option  to telnet.
I thought maybe this was a firewall issue on the Mac side, but the System Settings claim that the firewall is off. I'm also not running a third-party firewall. What could be causing this problem?

Routing tables:
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:~ andrewtapia$ netstat -rnf inet
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            10.204.221.1       UGScg                 en0
default            10.204.221.1       UGScIg                en1
default            link#25            UCSIg           bridge100      !
default            link#27            UCSIg           bridge101      !
default            link#31            UCSIg           bridge102      !
10.204.221/24      link#8             UCS                   en0      !
10.204.221/24      link#11            UCSI                  en1      !
10.204.221.1/32    link#8             UCS                   en0      !
10.204.221.1       a0:36:bc:75:66:18  UHLWIir               en0   1180
10.204.221.1       a0:36:bc:75:66:18  UHLWIir               en1   1197
10.204.221.1/32    link#11            UCSI                  en1      !
10.204.221.43/32   link#11            UCS                   en1      !
10.204.221.55/32   link#8             UCS                   en0      !
10.204.221.55      f0:18:98:ec:5a:9e  UHLWI                 lo0
10.204.221.95      3c:2a:f4:b9:e1:cd  UHLWI                 en0    814
10.204.221.95      3c:2a:f4:b9:e1:cd  UHLWI                 en1    814
10.204.221.106     f8:fe:5e:ae:c9:1e  UHLWI                 en0    994
10.204.221.243     8a:ef:7a:f7:e3:a6  UHLWI                 en0   1114
10.204.221.243     8a:ef:7a:f7:e3:a6  UHLWIi                en1   1114
10.204.221.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI                en0      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#8             UCS                   en0      !
169.254            link#11            UCSI                  en1      !
169.254.145.12     cc:a7:c1:25:d5:48  UHLSW                 en0      !
169.254.169.254    link#8             UHLSW                 en0      !
169.254.223.239    cc:a7:c1:25:d5:48  UHLSW                 en0      !
172.16.33/24       link#27            UC              bridge101      !
172.16.169/24      link#25            UC              bridge100      !
192.168.14         link#31            UC              bridge102      !
224.0.0/4          link#8             UmCS                  en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#11            UmCSI                 en1      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en1
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWIg         bridge101
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWIg         bridge102
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI                en0
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI                en1
255.255.255.255/32 link#8             UCS                   en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#11            UCSI                  en1      !

Route to 10.204.221.106:
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:~ andrewtapia$ route -n get 10.204.221.106
   route to: 10.204.221.106
destination: 10.204.221.106
  interface: en0
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,LLINFO,WASCLONED,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500       920

System Settings > General > Privacy & Security > Local Network settings:

Outputs of tcpdump -vvv -X -ni en0 -w capX.pcap 'port 31415 or arp' for:

telnet 10.204.221.106 31415
sudo -u nobody telnet 10.204.221.106 31415
nc 10.204.221.106 31415

Outputs of tcpdump -ni en0 -w capX.pcap for:

telnet 10.204.221.106 31415
sudo -u nobody telnet 10.204.221.106 31415

A diagram showing part of my network:


As suggested, I tried running ping -c1 -W1 10.204.221.106 before running the telnet command with and without sudo and recorded the output of arp -an at each step.
arp -an before running ping -c1 -W1 10.204.221.106:
? (10.204.221.1) at a0:36:bc:75:66:18 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.1) at a0:36:bc:75:66:18 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.6) at 80:e6:50:20:f6:c4 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.42) at c:4d:e9:ca:51:71 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.51) at 7c:10:c9:5e:7c:4e on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.51) at 7c:10:c9:5e:7c:4e on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.55) at f0:18:98:ec:5a:9e on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.95) at 3c:2a:f4:b9:e1:cd on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.95) at 3c:2a:f4:b9:e1:cd on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.159) at 46:56:8b:83:1c:f7 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.159) at (incomplete) on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.231) at 3c:6:30:eb:96:38 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.231) at 3c:6:30:eb:96:38 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.243) at 8a:ef:7a:f7:e3:a6 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.243) at 8a:ef:7a:f7:e3:a6 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en1 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en1 ifscope permanent [ethernet]

arp -an after ping -c1 -W1 10.204.221.106 and every other step:
? (10.204.221.1) at a0:36:bc:75:66:18 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.1) at a0:36:bc:75:66:18 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.6) at 80:e6:50:20:f6:c4 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.42) at c:4d:e9:ca:51:71 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.51) at 7c:10:c9:5e:7c:4e on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.51) at 7c:10:c9:5e:7c:4e on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.55) at f0:18:98:ec:5a:9e on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.95) at 3c:2a:f4:b9:e1:cd on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.95) at 3c:2a:f4:b9:e1:cd on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.106) at f8:fe:5e:ae:c9:1e on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.159) at 46:56:8b:83:1c:f7 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.159) at (incomplete) on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.231) at 3c:6:30:eb:96:38 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.231) at 3c:6:30:eb:96:38 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.243) at 8a:ef:7a:f7:e3:a6 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.243) at 8a:ef:7a:f7:e3:a6 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (10.204.221.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en1 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en1 ifscope permanent [ethernet]

Output of systemextensionsctl list:
0 extension(s)


The following C program exhibits the same behavior:
/* example.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>

int main() {
  struct addrinfo hints, *res;
  char* hostname = "10.204.221.106";
  char* portp = "31415";
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  int error = getaddrinfo(hostname, portp, &hints, &res);
  if (error != 0) {
    warn("getaddrinfo error");
    return 1;
  }
  int net = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
  if (net < 0) {
    warn("socket error");
    return 1;
  }
  if (connect(net, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    warn("connect error");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("success\n");
  return 0;
}

(base) Andrews-Mini-2:telnet andrewtapia$ gcc example.c
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:telnet andrewtapia$ ./a.out
a.out: connect error: No route to host
(base) Andrews-Mini-2:telnet andrewtapia$ sudo -u nobody ./a.out
success


What is the output of which telnet and sudo which telnet? Do other commands show a similar behavior, for example ping 10.204.221.106 and sudo ping 10.204.221.106?

@jaume telnet for me is /usr/local/bin/telnet with or without sudo. Some other programs do have the same behavior. I first encountered this problem with Deskflow, but ping and some other programs actually do not have the same behavior.

@AndrewTapia I can't reproduce this problem on my system (15.1) with the exact same telnet binary version (also from Homebrew). Strange. What is the output of the following two commands on your system: netstat -rnf inet and route -n get 10.204.221.106?

@luckman212 Thank you for trying to reproduce the issue. I've added the output of those commands to my question.

@AndrewTapia The output looks fairly normal. I'm wondering if this is a foundational macOS bug since you're a bit behind (there's even a 15.1.1 as of today). Sequoia had some notable networking bugs (see here and here) at launch. It could be TCC blocking access from your Terminal. What does System Settings → Privacy → Local Network look like? Any reason you can't update to the current OS?

@luckman212 I've added the Local Network settings in the question. 15.0.1 was the newest version when I first posted this question, but I haven't updated to a newer version yet because I use my Mac somewhat infrequently. I will try upgrading to the newest version and see if that improves the problem.

@luckman212 Unfortunately, updating to 15.1.1 doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

@AndrewTapia I think we need to go to tcpdump and make 2 packet captures, one where you use sudo and one without, and compare the bits on the wire to see what's going on. Try something like tcpdump -vvv -X -ni en0 -w cap1.pcap 'port 31415 or arp' and then open a new terminal and attempt your connection. Repeat with sudo and save as cap2.pcap. If you can post these somewhere they might contain the answer, or at least a clue.

@luckman212 Okay. I've added links to those outputs in the question.

@AndrewTapia I had a look at those pcaps. One thing that stood out to me is that in cap1 I don't see an ARP Who has 10.204.221.106? Tell 10.204.221.55 packet. Is there any difference in behavior if you pre-populate the arp cache by running ping -c1 -W1 10.204.221.106 immediately before running the telnet command? Anything else noteworthy about your network setup (additional switches, virtualization, etc)? Could you post output of arp -an immediately before and after running the non-sudo and sudo flavors of your commands?

@luckman212 I've added a network diagram showing part of my network and the outputs from the experiment you suggested.

@AndrewTapia I just re-read all the notes here, and I don't think we've established: Are you sure your system isn't running some sort of 3rd party network filtering app / firewall? (e.g. Little Snitch, LuLu, Radio Silence, Murus, Intego NetBarrier...) What is the output of systemextensionsctl list from Terminal?

@luckman212 I've added the output of that command to the question, but it doesn't show any extensions. I don't have a third-party firewall installed on the Mac.

@AndrewTapia If you're able to, please collect some new unfiltered packet captures while running the failing command. Try tcpdump -ni en0 -w cap4.pcap. There could be sensitive data collected in these captures, so quit all other apps first and take a look at the data in Wireshark (if you're worried about it) before posting.

@luckman212 Okay, I've added links to unfiltered captures for the telnet command with and without sudo.

Do you have the same problem with other telnet servers, including localhost? Do you have a .telnetrc file, and if so, what's in it?

@AndrewTapia I looked at the new pcaps. But really can't spot the issue. Any difference if you execute the telnet command with the -N flag? (skips rDNS lookup of IP address)

@LincDavis It doesn't look like I can connect to other computers on the network, but I can connect to a netcat listener running on localhost.

@luckman212 Thanks for taking a look. Passing -N to telnet doesn't appear to make a difference.

What about the telnetrc file, if any? Also, are you running it from the built-in Terminal app or from some other terminal emulator, such as iTerm?

@LincDavis I don't have a .telnetrc file. I'm running the commands from GNU Screen, but I've also seen the problem occur in the built-in Terminal app (when not attached to a screen).

Please try it in Terminal directly in a built-in shell, not a Homebrew shell.

You are not alone!! I've got the same error trying to connect to a mac on my local network.
I can browse to it just fine: https://mymac.local:8581 for homebridge or https://mymac.local:631 for the CUPS homepage. So there is a route to the machine.
But if I try to ping or ssh to this same machine, I get these sorts of errors:
ssh: connect to host mymac.local port 22: Undefined error: 0

PING mymac.local (192.168.1.100): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host

Note that I too am running 15.1.1 and the hint from the comments of running the commands via sudo also work which makes no sense to me.

Interesting twist: ssh works from the MacOS terminal app. Not from the terminal in vscode which is what I normally use... Both terminals using the same shell and environment. Both report /usr/bin/ssh when checking which ssh....

Not An Answer — the comments section has grown out of control and the latest ones are getting hidden, so I'm posting this here for visibility. I will delete it if and when a true answer is found.
I had a look at those pcaps. One thing that stood out to me is that in cap1 I don't see an ARP Who has 10.204.221.106? Tell 10.204.221.55 packet. Is there any difference in behavior if you warm up the arp cache by running ping -c1 -W1 10.204.221.106 immediately before running the telnet command?
Anything else noteworthy about your network setup (additional switches, virtualization, etc)?
Could you post output of arp -an immediately before and after running the non-sudo and sudo flavors of your commands?

I compiled a build of telnet based on the latest available GNU inetutils v2.5 source code from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/inetutils. Since you said you're on a Mac Mini 2018, I built it for x86_64 architecture.
Please give this build a try and let me know if it behaves any differently:
https://github.com/luckman212/gnu-telnet

I appreciate you building this for me (and your README), but this version of telnet doesn't seem to be behaving any differently.

I'm almost out of ideas @AndrewTapia. I'm sorry I couldn't solve this, but it's one of the most puzzling problems I've seen in years. I'm definitely staying tuned to this and hopefully someone smarter will come along with the answer!
